# Is there a way to add muliple productids within the same soap request envelope?

Tags: web-services, soap, request

It doesn't seem very efficient to send a single productId request one at a time in a soap envelope request, and then get 1 product response.

Is there any way to allow  for multiple multipart productId's  with the same request envelope?
An array or some other options, to allow for more than 1 product at a time?
For example to send single request for 20 products and get 20 products back in single response?

Thanks

[image: Soap Sample]

Answer (score 0):

If you have, let's say a C# method like the following:

```
public Product GetProduct(int productId) {
   Product p = null;
   // ... retrieve product here
   return p;
}
```

can you invoke it with 20 product ids and get back 20 products as a result?

You can't. Because that's not the definition of the method.

If you want to work with many product ids and products at the same time, there must be another method that does that for you, otherwise you are forced to use just the above method again and again.

A SOAP web service works the same way. It exposes operations that you can invoke. Those operations are just like the method above, but you can call them over the network using the SOAP protocol message instead of through code locally to your application. As such, the operations have a strong signature just like the method above.

If the SOAP web service only offers that operation from your print screen, then that's all you can call. If the SOAP web service were to provide another operation that works with lists of products, then you could invoke that one instead.

What you need to do is look in the WSDL of the web service to see what operations it offers and if there is one that you can use better. If you don't have other operations, then look carefully at the operation you have and see how many times the `<shar:productId>` is expected to appear in the message request. If it says `maxOccurs="unbounded"` then you might be able to send more ids. If it's `maxOccurs="1"` then you can only send one at a time.